# Spring Data JPA : java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found

Tags: spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

Trying to return list from column named `make` causes error in console where column `id` is not found.  The column named `id` is on the table but not sure why it is not recognized.

Car.java

```
 package com.example.demo;


import javax.persistence.Entity;
import javax.persistence.Id;


@Entity
public class Car {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private String make;
    private String model;
    private String year;


    public Car() {
    }

    public Car(String id, String make, String model, String year) {
        this.id = id;
        this.make = make;
        this.model = model;
        this.year = year;
    }

    public String getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(String id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getMake() {
        return make;
    }

    public void setMake(String make) {
        this.make = make;
    }

    public String getModel() {
        return model;
    }

    public void setModel(String model) {
        this.model = model;
    }

    public String getYear() {
        return year;
    }

    public void setYear(String year) {
        this.year = year;
    }
}
```

CarRepository.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.JpaRepository;
import org.springframework.data.jpa.repository.Query;

import java.util.List;

public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(value="SELECT make FROM car", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Car> getAllMakes();
}
```

CarController.java

```
package com.example.demo;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.Model;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ModelAttribute;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.PostMapping;


@Controller
public class CarController {



    @Autowired
    private CarService carService;

    @Autowired
    private CarRepository carRepository;



    @GetMapping("/car")
    public String carForm(Model model) {
        model.addAttribute("car", new Car());
        model.addAttribute("cars", carService.getAllCars());
        return "car";
    }

    @PostMapping("/car")
        carService.addCar(car);
        return "redirect:/car";
    }



    @GetMapping("/list")
    public String carMakeList(Model model){
        model.addAttribute("list", carRepository.getAllMakes());
        return "list";
    }


}
```

list.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
</head>
<body>
<h1>Car List</h1>

<table>
    <thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Id</th>
        <th>Make</th>
        <th>Model</th>
        <th>Year</th>
    </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
    <tr th:if="${!list}">
        <td colspan="2"> No Cars Available</td>
    </tr>

    <tr th:each="car : ${list}">

        <td><span th:text="${car.make}">Make</span></td>

    </tbody>
</table>
</body>
```

```
2019-08-30 10:12:31.008 ERROR 26538 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.h.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper   : Column 'id' not found.
2019-08-30 10:12:31.026 ERROR 26538 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] in context with path [] threw exception [Request processing failed; nested exception is org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: could not execute query; SQL [SELECT make FROM car]; nested exception is org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: could not execute query] with root cause

java.sql.SQLException: Column 'id' not found.
```

Comment: Maybe you should make it to be of type `Integer` instead of `String`?

Comment: you are not selecting make from the entity. You are no selecting id column

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to specify `*`(all) in your SQL query:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(value="SELECT * FROM car", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Car> getAllMakes();
}
```

The problem is `id` field is required for `Car` entity, you can also try:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(value="SELECT id,make FROM car", nativeQuery=true)
    List<Car> getAllMakes();
}
```

For your current query to work, you can use JPA projections and change your code to:

```
public interface CarRepository extends JpaRepository<Car, String> {
    @Query(value="SELECT make FROM car", nativeQuery=true)
    List<String> getAllMakes();
}
```

Comment: thank you.  The first query is working but puts the list of `make` under the column header `id` on my `list.html` instead of the column header under `make`.  How does using `*` instead of `make` work here?  How does it know I'm wanting to print all the `make`s when using `*`?

Comment: `List<Car> getAllMakes();` what is this doing exactly?

Comment: Ok,  I see why just `make` column was shown in view... because of my commenting.  How would I just get it to print a specified column only and not the complete table please?

Comment: sorry, I'm not following. You can specify any column in .html template

Comment: Thank you very much. I faced with the same problem.